# Generate an OD list of nodes within n stops

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph G(V,E),  the number of edges is 35000 and the number of nodes is 3500,
Is there anyway I can generate a origin-destination list within n (say 4) stops for each node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function [neighborhood()](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/neighborhood.html) does exactly what you want. Set the order argument to 4 and for each vertex you'll get a vector of vertex ids for the vertices that are at most 4 steps away from it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:
Use the property of the adjacency matrix A， the entry in row i and column j of A^n gives the number of (directed or undirected) walks of length n from vertex i to vertex j. So for n stop, construct n matrix An, A(n-1)......A1, in which, An= A^n. Then the **union of An,An-1....A1** should be the matrix that representing n stop reachable destinations for an origin.